# Importing from a python namespace in different folders

Tags: python, importerror

I have python code organized like this:

```
part_one
  namespace
    __init__.py
    one.py

part_two
  namespace
     __init__.py
     two.py
```

Where both `__init__.py` contain:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.declare_namespace("namespace")
```

My problem happens when I import them like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("part_one")
import namespace.one

sys.path.append("part_two")
import namespace.two # ImportError
```

Obvious fix is to move `path.append("part_two")` before `import namespace.one`, however the first import is in a script that my company uses to setup and start ipython, so I can't add part_two there (part_one is the core api of my company, part_two is my project).

An explanation as to why the error happens would also be nice.

Comment: When you cannot change the first import, a dirty workaround is probably `ns = namespace; del namespace; sys.path.append("part_two"); import namespace.two; namespace.one = ns.one; del ns`. But ... really?!?